# Writing multiple parquet files in parallel

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a big Spark `DataSet` (Java) & I need to apply filter to get multiple dataset and write each dataset to a parquet.

Does Java Spark provide any feature where it can write all parquet files in parallel? I am trying to avoid it to do it sequentially.

Other option is use Java `Thread`, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark will automatically write parquet files in parallel. It also depends on how many executor cores you provided as well as number of partitions of a dataframe. You can try using `df.write.parquet("/location/to/hdfs")` and see the time when those were written.

Comment: That's great then, I didn't know that.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it as answer or let me know

Answer (score 1):

Yes by default Spark provide parallelism using Spark Executors, but if want to achieve parallelism on Driver too, then you can do something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParallelSparkWrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = Constant.getSparkSess();

        Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().json("input/path");

        List<String> filterValue = new ArrayList<>();

        //Create a parallel stream
        filterValue.parallelStream()
                .forEach(filter -> {
                    //Filter your DataSet and write in parallel 
            ds.filter(ds.col("col1").equalTo(filter)).write().json("/output/path/"+filter+".json");
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Worth it really?

Comment: Yes we can utilize the idle Driver core(s) if required using ForkPool in Scala

Comment: Interesting, would need to think about that. .par familiar with but wherever I worked it was keep it simple.